# Node.js ntwitter login with twitter issue

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement login with twitter using the node.js ntwitter package.

https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter

I am able to make API calls correctly if I hardcode my credentials, however I am can't seem to  get the Oauth request for authentication to work.

I am using Express.js. I am just trying to get an initial 'toy' example to work so I have just created a separate route at this point that I am visiting directly

```
app.get('/twitter_login', function(req, res){
var twitter = require('ntwitter');
var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: '<Valid Consumer Key>',
    consumer_secret: '<Valid Consumer Secret'});
var tlog = twit.login(req,"/login_success");
tlog(res,req,null); //Not sure on this at all
```

Right now the error I receive is

```
DEBUG: TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:96:11)
    at handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ntwitter/lib/twitter.js:341:20)
    at <my app path>/app.js:47:3
```

I have a few questions

1. The ntwitter function returns a named function called 'handle'. Why is it named? What is the best way to call it?
2. Why is login being done in 2 phases? Why not just a login function?
3. Most Importantly: How do I get my users redirect to twitter so they can login?

I might be way off track here, but so feel free to suggest better methods. I would really like to stick to ntwitter though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

2 fundamental issues

1. The call into 'handle' has the paramaters out of order

   Originally I had

> tlog(res,req,null);

This should be

> tlog(res,req,null);

2.. I was rendering a template file at the end of twitter_login, which
        was causing issues  with redirect

======

To answer the original questions

**The ntwitter function returns a named function called 'handle'. Why is it named? What is the best way to call it?**

Named likely to make it easier to see in the call stack

It can be called as such

twit.login(path.pathname,"/twitter_callback")(req,res)

**Why is login being done in 2 phases? Why not just a login function?**

They are tied together, but the second call allows for a more idiomatic way to pass in the necessary information.

**Most Importantly: How do I get my users redirect to twitter so they can login?**

I have created a github repo that contains a working sample application.

https://github.com/drouillard/sample-ntwitter

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble as well with ntwitter. But, after looking at Twitter's API, I decided not to attempt my own wrapper

So, I got OAuth working by doing the normal process of redirecting to Twitter, then having my callback page that gets the access token. Once you have the token & secret that they pass you, you can use ntwitter like this:

```
var ntwitter = require('ntwitter');
var twit = new ntwitter({
    consumer_key: clientId,
    consumer_secret: secret,
    access_token_key: token,
    access_token_secret: tokenSecret    
})

// now you can do something like:
twit.getUserTimeline({
    include_rts: 1,
    count: 50
}, function(err, json) {
    // ...
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Marshall, Thanks for the quick response! That seems reasonable, and at this point might be what I end up doing. I get the feeling there is something fundamentally simple I am just not getting, as I just need the token key/secret, and ntwitter seems have a login function for this purpose. If I go the method you suggested I will accept this answer.